# Android TabActivity how to start Intent only on TabChange

Tags: android, android-intent, tabactivity, tabview

I have a problem with my Code:

I want to make a Highscore list with Google AppEngine and it works. Google AppEngine returns a String which is parsed and filled in a Layout.
The activity HighscoreListe connects to AppEngine and will get this string.

The problem with my Highscore layout in the way I wrote below is that this activity (HighscoreListe) starts multiple times when I start the TabLayout. So I get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I want to start intent2 when I change to Tab 2 and intent3 when I change to Tab3.
So that the highscores will only be loaded in the 2nd or 3rd difficulty when I click on this difficulty.

```
public class HighscoreTabLayout extends TabActivity{

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

       System.out.println(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties());
       int diffCount = -1;
       System.out.println(diffCount);

       TabSpec tabSpec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[++diffCount].getName());
       // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
       tabSpec1.setIndicator(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());//, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, HighscoreListe.class);
       intent1.putExtra("name", MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec1.setContent(intent1);
       System.out.println(diffCount);

       TabSpec tabSpec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[++diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec2.setIndicator(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());//, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
       Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, HighscoreListe.class);
       intent2.putExtra("name", MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec2.setContent(intent2);
       System.out.println(diffCount);

       TabSpec tabSpec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[++diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec3.setIndicator(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());//, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
       Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, HighscoreListe.class);
       intent3.putExtra("name", MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec3.setContent(intent3);
       System.out.println(diffCount);

       TabSpec tabSpec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[++diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec4.setIndicator(MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());//, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
       Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, HighscoreListe.class);
       intent4.putExtra("name", MenuMainActivity.getDifficulties()[diffCount].getName());
       tabSpec4.setContent(intent4);
       System.out.println(diffCount);

       // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
       tabHost.addTab(tabSpec1);
       tabHost.addTab(tabSpec2);
       tabHost.addTab(tabSpec3);
       tabHost.addTab(tabSpec4);

       tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if i got your point , you should set on tab chage listner on the tabhost :

` mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })`
```